# Tool for recording first chance exceptions without creating a crash dump file

Tags: windows, debugging

I have an application that throws hundreds of exceptions. I would like to know what type of exceptions there are. Unfortunately the issue is reproducible only on a production system, so performance is critical. Therefore I want to avoid long operations such as creating a crash dump. Also, I cannot modify the code.

Requirements:

- log first chance exceptions
- work on 32 and 64 bit
- do not capture a crash dump
- for Windows

I have tried:

- [FirstChanceExceptionEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888670/catching-first-chance-exceptions-in-managed-code-without-being-debugged), but that needs modifications in code
- [ProcDump](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) with the `-e 1` argument, but that one captures crash dumps
- [ADPlus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/adplus), but it captures crash dumps
- WinDbg script, but it's unstable for the amount of exceptions I have

I like free and open source software, but in this case I would even some spend money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) can log first chance exceptions in profiling mode. Open the executable, then choose "Start" from the "Profile" menu.

- It's free
- It does not take crash dumps
- There's a 32 bit and a 64 bit version

Downside: .NET exceptions are only logged as `0xE0434352 (unknown)`, so it's not very suitable for .NET.

[image: Screenshot of dependency walker]